# Можно ли в yandex map 3.0 составлять маршруты через несколько точек?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно сделать маршрут через несколько точек, можно ли это реализовать в yandex map 3.0?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Раз в GUI можно, то и в API можно, иначе было бы странно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс только начинает развивать API 3.0. Публичная панель маршрутов или функция для построения маршрута пока не реализованы или просто не открыты пользователям из-за недостаточной их проверки или иных причин.

Даже если где-то под капотом подобная функция уже есть, откапывать и использовать её из недр API [пользовательское соглашение Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/) запрещает. Нужно ждать, пока выкатят в прод.