# Как програмно построить маршрут в yandex картах API 3.0?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Я создаю карту для приложения и хочу чтобы по нажатию на маркер можно было построить маршут от заранее заданной точки до этого маркера или посмотреть панораму обьекта.

[image: выглядит это вот так:]

К сожалению, для 3.0 ни одного слова о построении маршрута или о панормах в документации я не нашел, а те немногие примеры, которые выложены на codesandbox.io все сделаны на react.

Подскажите, если знаете, где найти доки или где глянуть хотябы один примерчик по этим двум моментам.

Comment: Ответ пока тот же, что и про мультимаршруты: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1522570/386299